# Get associated parent models values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, associations

I have following models in my rails app:

*Unit* that **belongs to** a *User*

*User* that  **has many** *Units*

I have a scope to get all the Units in the warehouse that belongs to a unit

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :warehouse, where(:location => 'warehouse')
end
```

I also wrote a **cached_warehouse** method to get cached data, but I don't know how to read the user id from the parent model to create a cache for each User.

```
user = User.first
user.units.cached_warehouse
```

How to I access the id of the user in my cached_warehouse class method?

```
class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base    
  def self.cached_warehouse
    Rails.cache.fetch([name, "warehouse_#{USER_ID}"]) do
      warehouse.to_a
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Try this: `.fetch([name, "warehouse_#{self.user_id}"])`

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Because the Class method doesn't know anything about the association, I think.


NoMethodError: undefined method `user' for #<Class:0x007fc02d41a498>

Comment: This error is raiser by your `puts units.user`. Where is defined the `self.cached_warehouse` method? In User model or Unit?

Comment: The self.cached_warehouse is defined in the Units class. The call I do in my Controller is @user.units.cached_warehouse. self.unit.id isn't working in the Units Model. Should I move it to the User Model? I don't think it belongs there.

Comment: this method cached_warehouse is a class method (does not need an instance of Unit to be called) however you try to get the cache of a specific user. You have to either make this method an instance method (will fetch the catch of the instancied Unit and its user_id) or you can define self.cached_warehouse with a param, user_id.

Comment: Okay, I think I will try the params way, thanks